# The otput in 555 timer not change

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design, power-electronics

Can someone tell me why the output of the 555 timer doesn't change?

The output of the 555 timer is same as Vcc, I want the output same as the input.

[image]

Comment: come on, your PC has a "Screenshot" function. I mean, this isn't even a straight photograph. This is just lazy, and a lot of relevant fields aren't legible due to you not putting in a minimum amount of diligence in posting your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output to go low then keep the Trigger pin high for more than about 0.5 seconds after triggering. The output will not go low until after the TR pin has been taken high.